# Catch a click on item in ListCtrl with modifiers

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a virtual ListCtrl with single-selection mode. Now I want to customize clicks, shift-clicks and control-clicks on listitems. To do that I need to GetModifiers() during the event handler of wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED. How do I do that?

I tried the following:

1) Instantiate self.keyboard = wx.KeyboardState() during **init**() of my custom ListCtrl. Then call self.keyboard.GetModifiers() during the event handling.

2) Instantiate the KeyboardState-class during the event handling.

To test if it works I just print all the modifiers that are captured. But it is always 0 (i.e. MOD_NONE).

I also tried to use wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN and wx.EVT_LEFT_UP instead of wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED. The former has the same problems, the latter isn't even fired, when I click on a listitem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assigns both a mouse and an item selected event to the same thing, then uses `event.Skip()` to ensure that we see both.
Perhaps this might give you an idea on how to progress.
Use with Shift, Ctrl etc and combinations, `mods` will give you a different number depending on what is pressed.

```
import wx

class Myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        pan = wx.Panel(self)
        self.listC = wx.ListCtrl(pan, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.listC.InsertColumn(0, 'Column1', width=50)
        self.listC.InsertColumn(1, 'Column2', width=50)
        self.listC.InsertColumn(2, 'Column3', width=50)
        self.listC.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.ListClick)
        self.listC.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.ListSelected)
        self.listC.InsertStringItem(0,"Item1")
        self.listC.SetStringItem(0, 1,"Col 1 Item")
        self.listC.SetStringItem(0, 2,"Col 2 Item")
        self.listC.InsertStringItem(1,"Item2")
        self.listC.SetStringItem(1, 1,"Col 1 Item")
        self.listC.SetStringItem(1, 2,"Col 2 Item")

    def ListClick(self, event):
        mods = event.GetModifiers()
        print mods
        event.Skip()

    def ListSelected(self, event):
        print "selected"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = wx.App()
    Myframe().Show()
    App.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification.